# (k)ubuntu ssd and hdd. Hdd is read only

Tags: disk-usage, disk, readonly

I've a laptop with a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. I just installed kubuntu on it and mounted my SSD on

> /

and my HDD on

> /usr

But now when I want to install a Steam game om the HDD, it keeps saying that the disk is read-only. So how can I make it also writeable? (The weird thing is that there are already files on it)

EDIT: screenshot of the mount and df -hT command
[image]

Comment: How did you mount it? Can you should the output of the `mount` and `df -hT` commands? Steam games typically install to your home directory, not `/usr/`

Comment: Yes, I uploaded a screenshot in the question (the /dev/sda1 is the HDD)

Comment: I assume you can `touch` files on it?  Is the directory you told steam to write to have the right permissions that its writable by your user?

Comment: @rogerdpack no I couldn't. What I did to make it work was just `chown /usr myuser` and also `chmod 777`

Answer (score 0):

Check (and fix) your permissions for the folder you told it to write to, make sure your user can write to that folder.